# how to echo/access the 'get' index of the given array in PHP syntax

Tags: php, arrays

I have the array variable say $value, and it has the below given array

```
[navigation] => navigationHistory Object
        (
            [path] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [page] => order_form.php
                            [mode] => NONSSL
                            [get] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 31
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
```

how to echo/access the 'get' index of the given array in PHP syntax

Comment: thanx Col. i was about to edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering `$value` is an array and `$value['navigation']` is an object:

```
echo $value['navigation']->path[0]['get']['id'];
```

That is, only if `navigationHistory::$path` is `public`.

If not, see the class definition for `navigationHistory` to see if it doesn't have a getter for the field `path`.